# altBeacon: didEnterRegion

Tags: android, beacon

I'm writing an Android App custom Class that utilises AltBeacon's Android-Beacon-Library.
But when first start, If I'm in the beacon region, the didEnterRegion() won't work.
I want to create an event right away.
I can't find any other solution. Plz, Any help appreciated!
This is my code ▼

```
beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
                //Log.i(TAG, "I just saw an beacon for the first time!");
                sendData(dataStart);
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv_beacon_.setText("work");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
                //Log.i(TAG, "I no longer see an beacon");
                sendData(dataEnd);
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv_beacon_.setText("not work");
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int state, Region region) {
                Log.i(TAG, "I have just switched from seeing/not seeing beacons: "+state);

            }
```

Comment: if you are not in the beacon region when you start the app, is didEnterRegion() called when you actually enter the region ?

Comment: Yes, it called. But if it's already in didEnterRegion() or didExitRegion() at the beginning, it doesn't work until I make a change. How can I call it from the beginning?

Comment: ok. Check out my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected, because the `didEnterRegion` callback only fires if you are not already in the region. You can learn more about it here: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection-trouble.html

What you can do though, is call

```
beaconManager.setRegionStatePeristenceEnabled(false)
```

This will make the `didEnterRegion` callback fire after an app re-start, even if phone is already in the beacon region.

If you do this, bare in mind that the callback might fire multiple times when the app in background is temporarily killed by the Android OS.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks to your advice for solution!